# Render nested components from array on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map

I have a React parent component and I am using graphql to import my json data as a prop to be passed down to the child components. I'm trying to use state to update the page on click with one of three objects in my json file.

```
class Work extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({data: data.dataJson[0]})
    console.log(data.dataJson[0])

}
showPsContent() {
    this.setState({data: data.dataJson[1]})
}
render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const {data} = this.props
    console.log(data)
    console.log(this.props.data)
    return (
        <div id='work'>
            <NavBar/>
                <div className='work-content'>
                    <div className="side-nav">
                        <button onClick={() => 
     this.showContent(index)}></button>
                    </div>
                    <h1 className="work-header"></h1>
                    <Page data={this.state.data}/>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
   }
}
```

I need to pass the data by index number to my other components so that I can map over them.

Or should I map over the array in the parent array by storing it and changing state based on index.

My data looks like this :

```
{
"workpages": [{
        "title": "Escobar",
        "body": "is a registered 501(c)3 non-profit",
        "link": "https://excaliber.org",
        "mission": "https://excaliber.org/about#mission",
        "extab": {
            "label": "Summary",
            "text": "sie empre morter fybes losic masiknd" 
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "General Assembly",
        "body": "sie empre morter fybes losic masiknd",
        "link": "https://excaliber.org",
        "mission": "https://excaliber.org/about#mission",
        "extab": {
            "label": "Summary",
            "text": "sie empre morter fybes losic masiknd"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get the data in componentDidMount. After that, you can store the current page number/index in the state and increase/change it when button clicked. So, when you increase/change the page index, component will rerender childs and everything works good. Your component can be written like this:

```
class Work extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            currentPageIndex: 0
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // getting data somehow
        this.setState({data: jsonData});
    }

    showContent() {
        const nextIndex = this.state.currentPageIndex === this.state.data.length ? 0 : this.state.currentPageIndex + 1;
        this.setState({currentPageIndex: nextIndex});
    }

    render() {
        const {data, currentPageIndex} = this.state;
        return (
            <div id='work'>
                <NavBar />
                <div className='work-content'>
                    <div className="side-nav">
                        <button onClick={this.showContent}></button>
                    </div>
                    <h1 className="work-header"></h1>
                    <Page data={data ? data[currentPageIndex] : null} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually able to store my data from the graphql query (not shown) in state since its created and passed on as a prop during build. I made a slight adjustment so that the initial state was the first array and then the showContent function increased the array and set the state.